# How to display a field of a object linked by a foreign key in odoo / openerp?

Tags: xml, forms, odoo, field

I try to display the company_registry number of the client into the account.invoice_form.

In python, the field is addressed by `(my_invoice_object).partner_id.company_registry`

In xml I tried several things but nothing worked. Here is one of my attempts :

```
    <record id="view_invoice_form_tis" model="ir.ui.view">
        <field name="name">view_invoice_form_tis</field>
        <field name="model">account.invoice</field>
        <field name="inherit_id" ref="account.invoice_form"/>
        <field name="arch" type="xml">
            <xpath expr="//field[@name='move_id']" position="after">
                <field name="partner_id.company_registry"/>
            </xpath>
        </field>
    </record>
```

Does anybody has the trick ?

Herve

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing. Add a new field in your model and save your required values to that field. Then display your new field. 
In XML dot operation won't work

Answer (score -1):

What are you doing totally wrong. You have to first learn odoo. You can get technical guide from [odoo documentation site](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/10.0/).

for this thing you have to put related field in .py file, then you can add field in view.

Hope this help.

Comment: yes, it helps, thanks - I just hoped I didn't need to add the field in my python object because it is already in a sub-object. Thanks for your answer.